# Why does exporting GridView shows empty Excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have an `Export to Excel` button which has the following code:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=yourTaskList.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    yourTasksGV.AllowPaging = false;
    yourTasksGV.DataBind();

    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background", "#CCCCCC");

    //Apply style to Individual Cells
    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#E2E2E2");
    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#E2E2E2");
    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#E2E2E2");
    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#E2E2E2");
    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#E2E2E2");
    yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#E2E2E2");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        yourTasksGV.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("height", "30px");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < yourTasksGV.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = yourTasksGV.Rows[i];

        //Change Color back to white
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        //Apply text style to each Row
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

        //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
        }
    }

    yourTasksGV.RenderControl(hw);

    //style to format numbers to string
    string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

My `GridView` shows this:

[image]

When I export, this is what is saved:

[image]

Why is it saving empty data and not the data that is being shown in the `GridView`?

Comment: I think you forgot to give `yourTasksGV` a DataSource before you bound it?

Comment: I added it and it still not showing any data. When I debug, it go in to the `RowDataBound` function but skips over it, it then go in to the `RowCreated` function but skips over it.

Comment: Your way of generating Excel files isn't very maintainable. Instead of building up HTML you should find a library that generates actual Excel files and runs on the server, such [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling DataBind again inside of `btnExport_Click` without setting the DataSource property of the grid. Unless you are turning off ViewState, you shouldn't need to rebind at all though. Just delete `yourTasksGV.DataBind();` 
altogether.